# MySQL Fulltextsearch + not working as expected

Tags: mysql

I try to test MySQL Fulltextsearch compared to SOLR. I set up an InnoDB table with an int-key and a longtext field including a fulltextindex.

CREATE TABLE `cvtext` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cvtext` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `cvtext` (`cvtext`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

By the way - I'm using MySQL 4.6.16 and ft_min_word_len=3.

My question is regarding the boolean search:

1) **select * from cvtext where MATCH(cvtext) AGAINST('+SQL')** => results in:

- 2    oracle SQL database developer
- 1    oracle SQL database entwickler
- 3    oracle SQL database
- 5    oracle SQL datenbank developer entwickler

2) **select * from cvtext where MATCH(cvtext) AGAINST('+SQL +oracle')** => results in:

- 2 oracle SQL database developer
- 1 oracle SQL database entwickler
- 3 oracle SQL database
- 5 oracle SQL datenbank developer entwickler
- 4 oracle datawarehouse developer entwickler

So the first query is i.m.h.o. correct and returns only records with SQL included. The second query should do the same since I use '+' but it also returns record no 4. which doesn't contain SQL.

Any ideas what could be wrong or did I not understand the query logic?

Comment: Are those results you have shown the _full_ content of the `cvtext` column?

Comment: I think you need to run the query `IN BOOLEAN MODE` for those special characters ('+', '-') to be interpreted. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: Thank you Pevara, that was the solution !! I thought that boolean mode is the default!